# Set and Oldset in sigprocmask()

Tags: c, posix, signals, sigprocmask

I haven't completely understood, how to use `sigprocmask()`. Particularly, how the `set` and `oldset` and its syntax work and how to use them.

```
int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *set, sigset_t *oldset);
```

Please explain with an example, to block, say SIGUSR1 for a few seconds and then unblock and handle it.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The idea is that you provide a mask in `set`, effectively a list of signals.  The `how` argument says what you should do with the mask in `set`.

You can either use `SIG_BLOCK` to block the signals in the `set` list, or `SIG_UNBLOCK` to unblock them.  Neither of these changes the signals that aren't set in the list.  `SIG_SETMASK` blocks the signals in the list, and unblocks the ones that aren't set in the list.

For instance, assume that the old blocking list was `{SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP}` and you call `sigprocmask` with these arguments:

```
sigset_t x;
sigemptyset (&x);
sigaddset(&x, SIGUSR1);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &x, NULL)
```

The new blocking list will now be `{SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP, SIGUSR1}`.

If you call `sigprocmask` with these arguments now:

```
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &x, NULL)
```

The new blocking list will go back to being `{SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP}`.

If you call `sigprocmask` with these arguments now:

```
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &x, NULL)
```

The new blocking list will now be set to `{SIGUSR1}`.

The `oldset` argument tells you what the previous blocking list was.  If we have this declaration:

```
sigset_t y;
```

and we call the code in the previous examples like this:

```
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &x, &y)
```

now we have:

```
y == {SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP}
```

If we now do:

```
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &x, &y)
```

we'll get

```
y == {SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP, SIGUSR1}
```

and if we do:

```
    sigprocmask(SIG_SET, &x, &y)
```

we'll get this:

```
y == {SIGSEGV, SIGSUSP}
```

because this is the previous value of the blocking set.