# Reset mask of ignored signal in Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

During `exec()` the mask of blocked signals (as set by `sigprocmask()`) is inherited by child processes.

But now I've noticed that under Linux, there is also mask of ignored signals (`grep < /proc/self/status ^SigIgn`), and it's also inherited by child processes. Since these are set by `sigaction()` with `act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN`, I would have expected that, as signal handlers, they are reset during exec. But they are not.

Consider example below: parent wants to ignore the SIGINT, but that also extends to the child, thus the `sleep 120` can't be killed with `kill -INT $(pidof sleep)` anymore.

Questions:

1. Is this POSIX compliant? Documentation of [sigaction()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) explicitly states that effect of `sigaction` doesn't survive `exec` (Quote: "*... until one of the exec functions is called*"). Linux man page says "*the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged*" which I guess makes that a Linux specific feature.
2. How to reset the ignore mask correctly & reliably? I have found no analog of `sigprocmask()`  - manages blocked signals - to manage the mask of ignored signals. Should I simply iterate over all signals and reset them with `sigaction()`?

P.S. Tested with kernels v3.x & v4.9, same behavior.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t ss;

    system("grep -n < /proc/self/status ^SigIgn");

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction( SIGINT, &act, NULL );

    system("grep -n < /proc/self/status ^SigIgn");

    sigemptyset(&ss);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &ss, NULL);

    system("grep -n < /proc/self/status ^SigIgn");

    system("sleep 120");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `sigprocmask` together with `sigemptyset` to reset blocked signals of your forks ? This may help you : [Set and Oldset in sigprocmask()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261/set-and-oldset-in-sigprocmask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this POSIX compliant?

Yes, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html specifies that:

> Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process
>   image shall be set to the default action in the new process image.
>   Except for SIGCHLD, **signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling
>   process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image**.
>   Signals set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to
>   the default action in the new process image (see ).

(emphasis mine)

**Blocked**-signals masks, **default**-signals mask, and **ignored**-signals masks are all inherited across `exec*` calls in POSIX, although POSIX doesn't really have a concept of the latter two masks (they're just special signal  dispositions, set for each signal separately, unlike blocked-signals masks which can be modified en-masse).

> 2. How to reset the ignore mask correctly & reliably? I have found no
>      analog of sigprocmask() - manages blocked signals - to manage the mask
>      of ignored signals. Should I simply iterate over all signals and reset
>      them with sigaction()?

Yes—iterate over the signals with `sigaction` or `signal`. (While `sigaction` should otherwise be preferred, for setting signals to `SIG_IGN`/`SIG_DFL`, signal is sufficient, portable, and more compact.). Ideally this should be done after `fork()` to prevent races with other threads (signal dispositions are shared global state).

Even better, you can use `posix_spawn`/`posix_spawnp` with an attribute (`posix_spawnattr_t`) that specifies the set of signals that should be reset to default in the child process. The `posix_spawnattr_setsigdefault` attribute-setter can be used to specify this signal set.